# What is bd-highlight in Bootstrap 4.1?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

On the bootstrap 4.1 documentation page for [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors), there are several examples where the class `bd-highlight` is used. For example:

```
<div class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight">I'm a flexbox container!</div>
```

What is the use of `bd-highlight`?
There doesn't seems to be any documentation for this class.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I think this is just a custom css class to highlight the examples, i.e., set background color and borders, on the documentation pages.

```
.bd-highlight {
    background-color: rgba(86,61,124,0.15);
    border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,0.15);
}
```

bd = Bootstrap Documentation?